# Wireshark Related : Option to take packet and modify contents

Tags: wireshark

Is there any option to capture a packet eg(Http) , modify certains aspects of it (Checksum-validate False to True ) and resend it using Wireshark ?

Answer (score 1):

[Ettercap NG filters](http://obnalichim.blogspot.com/2012/12/ettercap-ng.html) can do such a job properly, here is example on link

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible using wireshark. Wireshark is a packet analyzer.

Perhaps iptables could help you there.

Answer (score 0):

No, WireShark doesn't do this.  What you are looking for is Fiddler which allows you to monitor HTTP traffic and "fiddle" with incoming or outgoing traffic.  So you can capture HTTP traffic, modify it and resend.

Find it here: http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Check out the [demonstration videos](http://fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/video/default.asp) for more info, especially:

- [Using the Fiddler AutoResponder](http://fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/video/FiddlerSimpleTampering.wmv)
- [Replaying Modified Responses with AutoResponder](http://fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/video/AutoResponderReplay.wmv)

Comment: fiddler does not capture all traffic only these ports (21,80,443) how about RTMP (1935) ?

Answer (score 0):

try the free version of Colasoft ( http://www.colasoft.com/download/products/download_packet_builder.php ). the only hitch is you'll have to save the capture stream into a "xxx.cap" format but no worries wirshark can handle it...